# Microsoft Azure Backup On-Premise Server Failure

Tags: azure, disaster-recovery

I am running Microsoft Azure Backup, on-premise, and on the same machine that host my Hyper-V machines.  I am backing up all my VM's on the machine both locally and in Azure Recovery Services (online).  If that machine fails, or has some DR issue, can I restore from the Azure Portal.   The portal itself only show consumed drive space and I was searching for a way to recover a VM if I did not have the Azure Backup Server.   If I can not do this, how do you recommend I protect my VM's?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, maybe we can try to use other ways to protect our VMs on Azure.

1. We can use **System Center Data Protection Manager** **(DPM)** to protect our VMs, System Center DPM backs up file and application data. Data backed up to DPM can be stored on tape, on disk, or backed up to Azure with Microsoft Azure Backup. More information about DPM, please refer to the link below:
   https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh758173.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
2. Also we can use **Azure Backup** to protect our VMs, Azure Backup is the service that you use to back up and restore your data in the Microsoft cloud. It replaces your existing on-premises or off-site backup solution with a cloud-based solution that is reliable, secure, and cost-competitive. More information about Azure Backup, please refer to the link below:
   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-introduction-to-azure-backup/

If you still have questions, welcome to post back here. Thanks.

Comment: I am running Azure Backup on-prem, which is just like DPM,   The problem with DPM is that if the DPM server Fails and you do not have a copy of your database somewhere, you lose all your restore points.   In my scenario, I have my DPM server on my HYPER-V server so if I lost the sever I would lose my ability to recover and my Hyper V machines, so that would be catastrophic.  I was hoping that there was a way I could restore from Azure without the Azure Backup Server running on prem.

Comment: sorry, I understand what you mean. Azure recovery services vault can back up VMs to Azure Storage, it is not running On-premise. We can set backup policy to automatic backup VMs, set storage replication to choose geo-redundant or locally redundant storage. More information about recovery services vault, please refer to the link below:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms-first-look-arm/
If you still have questions, welcome to post back here. Thanks.